# Iterating through and manipulating nested lists in python

Tags: python, algorithm, replace, nested-lists

I have a nested list containing over a thousand sublists like this

```
x=[[1,2,4,4,5],[1,2,5,4,5],[1,2,5,4,5],[1,2,4,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]....]
```

I want to iterate over this and check a particular sequence of integers within all sublists. If the sequence of the third element `{x[2]}` in three consecutive sublists is 4,5,5, then I want the value of these integers alone to be replaced by 9,10 and 11 respectively. In the example provided above, my new list would look like

```
x=[[1,2,9,4,5],[1,2,10,4,5],[1,2,11,4,5],[1,2,4,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],....]
```

I'm using python 2.7. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the code you've written so far.

Comment: did you have any try before that you encounter with a problem in it ? if its so , show us your code till we could help you !

Comment: This is one step of a huge data manipulation process, I couldn't figure out where to even begin with this one, so I hadn't written anything thus far. I'm going to implement slaters logic and see if it works.

Comment: This works, thanks for all your help-                                                      for i in range(len(linelist)-2):
        if ((linelist[i][2]==4) and (linelist[i+1][2]==5) and (linelist[i+2][2]==5)):
            linelist[i][2] = 9
            linelist[i+1][2] = 10
            linelist[i+2][2] = 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is relatively using the `enumerate` keyword in python.

Specifically in your case since it seems all of the nested lists are at the same level you can just iterate through the top-level list:

```
for index, item in enumerate(x):
    if (item[2], x[index+1][2], x[index+2][2]) == (4, 5, 5):
        item[2] = 9
        x[index+1][2] = 10
        x[index+2][2] = 11
```

That said, there are a few edge cases here you'll want to deal with, which I won't spoonfeed you answers for. Specifically, is there any issue when we start reaching the end of the list?

Also, the code above isn't great, you can make it much more usable and general. This only covers the basic cases.

This should be the proof of concept, but you should make sure you understand this and can add to it before trying to go further.

Comment: This is one of those cases where I might use `range` directly instead of enumerate, to preserve the symmetry between each element of the tuple instead of special-casing the first, but it doesn't matter much.

Comment: @DSM I would probably agree if I were actually using this, but I tried to intentionally make this solution encapsulate the idea and not quite be a perfect plug-and-play solution. Thanks for the suggestion though, should help OP explore further.

Comment: Thanks Slater and DSM! this is what I use, and it worked like a charm-  for i in range(len(linelist)-2):
        if ((linelist[i][2]==4) and (linelist[i+1][2]==5) and (linelist[i+2][2]==5)):
            linelist[i][2] = 9
            linelist[i+1][2] = 10
            linelist[i+2][2] = 11

Comment: @py_beginner so glad that it helped! If this answer solved your problem don't forget to accept it (the green check below the upvotes)